# Azure Data Factory replace \ with '\\'. How to remove this?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure SQL Table that store file storage location copy activity. Like this:

```
FileName    Location
text.csv    \\Server\Test\TargetFolder
```

When I try to build a Lookup + Copy in Azure Data Factory. The lookup result always return this
`\\\\Server\\Test\\TargetFolder << ADF add an extra "\" for each "\"`.

Is there anyways I can remove this behavior?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the replace function , something like `@replace(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Location,'\\','\')` . I added a Setvariable activity and add the expression

I did some testing and it does the trick .

[image]
[image]